# Youtube embedded player not working on the physical device

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube, youtube-api, ytplayerview

I followed the [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper) on how to embed youtube player in my ios application. The application works perfectly on the simulator. When I load it on the physical device it gives me a black screen but with no actions at all. I checked if I go to the right view controller and I found myself in the correct one.

Comment: Provide more detail so people can help you on this. Did you put breakpoint on the code to see if your view or viewController is really loading?

Comment: I put a breakpoint on the code that make the player ready , but it just passing it silently . Also I put a nslog message in the method that should be executed to make the player appear , but it didn't print the message even.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you are embedding the You Tube API on a Apple device that runs iOS 7.0 or greater.

Comment: the device runs iOS 8.3